# Creating xml using stream, encoding attribute is missing

Tags: java, xml

I create xml using code like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XMLOutputFactory factory      = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventFactory  eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            XMLEventWriter writer =
                    factory.createXMLEventWriter(System.out);

            XMLEvent event = eventFactory.createStartDocument("utf-8");
            writer.add(event);

            event = eventFactory.createStartElement(
                    "", "", "test");
            writer.add(event);
            event = eventFactory.createEndElement(
                    "", "", "test");
            writer.add(event);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But in header attribute encoding is missing. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding is missing only for "utf-8". If you specify a different encoding, the encoding is included in the XML declaration. UTF-8 is the default encoding for XML so this is not really an error.

But if you are not using `System.out` the encoding is included even for "UTF-8". Here for example with a `StringWriter`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  XMLOutputFactory factory      = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
  XMLEventFactory  eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
  try {

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    XMLEventWriter writer =
        factory.createXMLEventWriter(sw);

    XMLEvent event = eventFactory.createStartDocument("utf-8");
    writer.add(event);

    event = eventFactory.createStartElement(
        "", "", "test");
    writer.add(event);
    event = eventFactory.createEndElement(
        "", "", "test");
    writer.add(event);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    sw.close();
    System.out.println(sw.toString());

  } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Then the result is: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><test></test>`